# Python -how to write to a specific position(column) in text file

Tags: python

I have the following fields in my program and i want to write these to a text file in specific position or columns,
say ID in column 1,Name in column 10 and email in column 30.

I tried using ,

```
fhand = open('test.txt','w')    
id,name,email = 1,'abc','abc@email.com'
id1,name1,email1 = 2,'adfadsfbnn','addbnn@email.com'
fhand.write('%s %10s %30s \n' %(id,name,email) )
fhand.write('%s %10s %30s \n' %(id1,name1,email1) )
fhand.close()

test.txt file contains,
1        abc                  abc@email.com 
2 adfadsfbnn               addbnn@email.com
```

The data is not gettting printed in the correct positions and I dont want the string to be right intended..I want 
the string to start printing from postion 10,30 respectively .Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: The numbers in the format specifications are field widths, not column numbers.  If the number is preceded by a minus sign, the field gets left justified, so try: ``'%-9s %-19s %s\n'`` for your format strings.

Comment: Give us an example of the specific columns in the text file

Comment: Thank you very much.that worked!!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter

```
fhand = open('test.txt','w')
id,name,email = 1,'abc','abc@email.com'
id1,name1,email1 = 2,'adfadsfbnn','addbnn@email.com'
fhand.write('%s %+50s %+80s \n' % (id,name,email))
fhand.write('%s %+50s %+80s \n' % (id1,name1,email1))
fhand.close()
```

Comment: Thank you..I wanted the strings left justified.. fhand.write('%s %-50s %-80s \n' % (id,name,email))
fhand.write('%s %-50s %-80s \n' % (id1,name1,email1))